# WatiN DialogHandler WaitUntilExists times out in IE9

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-9, watin

I'm trying to click OK on the dialog that pops up.  I've read that IE9 doesn't work well with WatiN's dialog handlers.  I'm using WatiN-2.1.0.1196-net-4.0.

Below is my method. Basically it goes to the alerts page.  On that page you can click delete individually per line or select several checkboxes and delete in bulk.  I grab the first delete button in a collection of individual alert delete buttons and check to see if it exists.  If so, click the select all button then click the delete all selected alerts button.

Everything seems to work up to that point and the dialog to confirm delete is now up.  The method then times out on browser.waituntilexists().

I've tried increasing the wait time and I've tried switching the handler type to DialogHandler, ConfirmDialogHandler, AlertDialogHandler, etc.  None of them seem to find the dialog window that pops up.

I need a work around so that I can confirm this dialog.

```
    private void DeleteAlerts(Browser browser)
    {
        browser.GoTo(URLs.CompleteUrl + "/alerts.aspx?apid=" + PID);
        while (browser.Page<AlertsAspx>().deleteMessage.Exists)
        {
            var handler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
            browser.Page<AlertsAspx>().SelectAll.Click();
            using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, handler))
            {
                //Assert.Fail("Never Sees Dialog");
                browser.Page<AlertsAspx>().Delete.ClickNoWait();
                handler.WaitUntilExists(50);
                handler.OKButton.Click();
                browser.WaitForComplete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you wired up the handler yet? You need to spin it up like an event.

Comment: what do you mean by wired it up? I have this line in there:
    var handler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();

Comment: To avoid any confusion, my variable "browser" is an IE instance that is already on my correct page.  For that reason, I do not need to declare a new IE object.  Likewise, I have a page class that creates more or less a static instance of the page class between the < and the >.  So when I say "browser.Page<AlertsAspx>()", that's declaring a bunch of predefined elements on that page.  Delete is a button on that page.

Comment: So are you saying the button your wanting to click is on the page and isnt a dialgbox?

Comment: no, I'm not needing to declare an ie.Button("myButton1") since it's already declared on the page class.  Clicking that button causes a dialog to pop up which WatiN isn't seeing.

Comment: just tried the following two other things which didn't work:
    var handler = new ReturnDialogHandlerIe9();
    var handler = ReturnDialogHandler.CreateInstance();

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick an dirty way of doing it:

```
    public void ConfirmOKTest()
{
    using (IE ie = new IE("http://localhost/confirmtest.htm"))
    {
        ConfirmDialogHandler handler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
        using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, handler))
        {
            ie.Button("myButton1").ClickNoWait();
            handler.WaitUntilExists();
            handler.OKButton.Click();
        }
        ie.WaitForComplete();
        Assert.AreEqual("Clicked OK", ie.Button("myButton1").Text);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I don't know why my code isnt formatting.

Edit: Finally got it.

Comment: I don't see any difference here and with my code aside from declaring a new browser instance instead of passing it and moving the wait for complete to outside of the using block.

Comment: I tried what you have and that doesn't seem to work either.  It's something with IE9, not with my code from what I've read.

Comment: Watin only tested to work with certain IE versions. Check out their website for more information. Im using 8 and the confirmDialogHandler works perfect.

Comment: exactly.  That's why I asked the question.  I'm looking for a work around so that I can click OK on a dialog in IE 9. BTW, WatiN does support IE 9 in their latest release.  
http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-1-0-1196/